# How to select the number element using selenium?

Tags: selenium

strong textI have an html table. I need to get the number "10 **strong text** "of a td element with selenium.

**Html structure:**

```
<td class="datepicker-day-number notranslate">
<td class="datepicker-day-number notranslate">
<button class="datepicker-cal-date" type="button" data-year="2018" data-month="3" data-day="10">10</button>
</td>
```

I tried using dynamic xpath :

```
//div[@class='datepicker-cal-month'][position()=1]//td
```

please how to select the date value 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this xpath -- `//td[@class='datepicker-day-number notranslate']/button[@class='datepicker-cal-date'][.='10']`

Comment: i need to select the number for selecting the date .

Comment: Updated answer that you want to select the button with '10'. This 10 is variable..